# Floated divs staying in div container / not wrapping on browser resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble preventing my floating divs from wrapping when I resize the browser. I'm brand new so try to ignore the terrible coding. I could achieve what I want with absolute positioning but I'm trying not to rely on that.

HTML

```
<div id="secondBar">
    <ul id="resultChoice">
        <div id="all"><li><a href="">All</a></li></div>
        <div id="videos"><li><a href="">Videos</a></li></div>
        <div id="maps"><li><a href="">Maps</a></li></div>
        <div id="shopping"><li><a href="">Shopping</a></li></div>
        <div id="news"><li><a href="">News</a></li></div>
        <div id="more"><li><a href="">More</a></li></div>
        <div id="searchTools"><li><a href="">Search Tools</a></li></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#secondBar {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    width: 100%;
}
#resultChoice {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#resultChoice div {
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#resultChoice div li {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #777;
    font-size: small;
}
```

Now I figured out that if the container that contains the floated items has a fixed width, then my list items will behave how I want and not wrap under. But, I was the container to be the full monitor width. I tried width 100% and that didn't work.

Is there anyway I can achieve this without a fixed width? A fixed width will look different on different monitors and not go edge to edge correct?

Comment: First thing to look at is using the `div's` around the `li`. You can add the id directly to the `li` like so: `<li id="all">`.
Also to make your list items fit the space and not wrap, you need a percentage width setting on them.

Comment: What do you want to have happen when the width is too small to contain all the list items?...and as has been said, `div` cannot be children of a `ul`...only `li` are allowed.

Comment: Note, I've removed my answer as upon re-reading your question, I'm unsure of what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I knew that divs inside the list was probably wrong ahha. I'm trying to make it so that if the browser resizes the list items remain where they are. So they don't wrap under or squish, they just remain in a fixed position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first of all**, `ul` can only have `li` for childs, and `li` can only have `ul` or `ol` for parent.

*`div` has to go or `ul` turn to `nav` for instance, and `li` deleted or turned into a neutral `span`.*

you may style `li` instead `div` and `a` instead `li`, in order to have a valid and fonctionnal code.

To avoid wrapping `li`s , you may use `display:table`/`table-cell` instead float + inline-block. (`display:flex` would do too ).

example:

```css
#secondBar {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
#resultChoice {
  display: table;
  /* you may wish to center your links: */
  /*  margin:auto;
  will do */
  /* eventually add some space aside each */
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#resultChoice li {
  height: 60px;/* here or on ul */
  display: table-cell;
  ;
}
#resultChoice li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;/* try to remove this and use vertical-align:bottom on li instead */
  color: #777;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondBar">
  <ul id="resultChoice">
    <li id="all"><a href="">All</a>
    </li>
    <li id="videos"><a href="">Videos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="maps"><a href="">Maps</a>
    </li>
    <li id="shopping"><a href="">Shopping</a>
    </li>
    <li id="news"><a href="">News</a>
    </li>
    <li id="more"><a href="">More</a>
    </li>
    <li id="searchTools"><a href="">Search Tools</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If no float no need to deal with it, height is no longer needed on parent :)

to play with: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgMmrR

Comment: Thanks so much! This achieved exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle which achieves what I think you need: https://jsfiddle.net/vuLg43ge/

```
<ul id="resultChoice">
    <li id="all"><a href="">All</a></li><!--
    --><li id="videos"><a href="">Videos</a></li><!--
    --><li id="maps"><a href="">Maps</a></li><!--
    --><li id="shopping"><a href="">Shopping</a></li><!--
    --><li id="news"><a href="">News</a></li><!--
    --><li id="more"><a href="">More</a></li><!--
    --><li id="searchTools"><a href="">Search Tools</a></li>
</ul>
```

You will see that I removed the `<div id="...` from the list and added the id's straight to the list items. I've also added a fix to remove the white space from the inline items, read more here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```
#resultChoice li {
    height: 60px;
    width: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #777;
    font-size: small;
}
```

In the CSS you can see I've added a percentage width to the list items: `width: 14%;` which means that each item in your list will take up 14% of the space available to it.

As your screen shrinks you should add media queries to make it look better as needed.